# How to refer to a document.createElement in CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm selecting data from an API which i then make into Objects with document.createElement but how can i style them?

Here's my Js code:

```
  fetch('https://randomuser.me/api/?results=5&nat=us').then(response =>{
        return response.json();
    }).then(responseJson=>{
        responseJson.results
        console.log(responseJson);

        for(const user of responseJson.results){
            const img = document.createElement ("IMG");
            img.innertext = user.picture.medium;
            img.setAttribute("src", user.picture.medium)
            img.setAttribute("width", "50");
            img.setAttribute("height", "50");
            img.setAttribute("alt", "");
            document.body.appendChild(img)

            const name = document.createElement("SPAN");
            name.innerText = user.name.first;
            document.body.appendChild(name);

            const phone = document.createElement("SPAN");
            phone.innerText = user.phone;
            document.body.appendChild(phone);

            console.log(user);
        }
    })
```

I've tried to refer to the name.innerText But that didn't work either. However i can refer to them all by calling,
Example:

```
span {
 color: blue;
}
```

And when i inspect the code it shows that the span it creates has no id what so ever, May that be the problem?

Comment: Why don't you set a `className`  and define that CSS class?

Comment: @connexo I've tried it but it's making it worse. I have 5 users and when i create a .className it only creates 1 user with the image only and leaves everything out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `className.add` on the created element to assign a CSS class to it. I've modified your code to make all the names bold and the phone number blue and underlined.

```js
fetch('https://randomuser.me/api/?results=5&nat=us').then(response =>{
    return response.json();
}).then(responseJson=>{
    responseJson.results
    console.log(responseJson);

    for(const user of responseJson.results){
        const img = document.createElement ("IMG");
        img.innertext = user.picture.medium;
        img.setAttribute("src", user.picture.medium)
        img.setAttribute("width", "50");
        img.setAttribute("height", "50");
        img.setAttribute("alt", "");
        document.body.appendChild(img)

        const name = document.createElement("SPAN");
        // Assign a CSS class name to the element.
        name.classList.add('user-name');
        name.innerText = user.name.first;
        document.body.appendChild(name);

        const phone = document.createElement("SPAN");
        phone.classList.add('phone-number');
        phone.innerText = user.phone;
        document.body.appendChild(phone);

        console.log(user);
    }
});
```

```css
.user-name {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.phone-number {
  color: blue;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Comment: Note that the img part could be simplified to `const img = new Image(50, 50); img.src = user.picture.medium;`.

Answer (score 3):

To style these elements there is two ways:

1. Add inline CSS to elements itself.

   `phone.style.color = 'blue';`
2. Add some ID or class to element and then refer to them

   `phone.className += "my-element";`

   `.my-element {color: blue;}`

Comment: `phone.className += "my-element"` should better be `phone.className += " my-element"`, or even better `phone.classList.add("my-element")`.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a `className` and create that CSS class in your CSS code:

```js
// Javascript
let blue = document.createElement('p');
let orange = document.createElement('p');

blue.textContent = "blue text";
orange.textContent = "orange text";

blue.className = "blue";
orange.className = "orange";

app.appendChild(blue);
app.appendChild(orange);
```

```css
/* CSS */
.blue { color: blue; }
.orange { color: orange; }
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: I've tried it but it's making it worse. I have 5 users and when i create a .className it only creates 1 user with the image only and leaves everything out.

Comment: Show your attempt then.

Comment: Could you give me a moment please? I'm trying @Thijs's answer.

Comment: Connexo i've tried stijn's answer and it is working. Your method would've worked aswell but apparently i had put the .className on the end of the span like: const name = document.createElement("SPAN").className = "name";

Comment: Yeah, you might be used to chaining tasks from jQuery, unfortunately in many cases this doesn't work with the native API in the same way. I tried to give a more generic answer independent of your current code problem, which is reduce to the core of what you are asking.

Comment: Yeah i figured so to. I'm still learning how to code in vanilla js so thank you again.